# How can be created a filter in jira that contains the sum of time spent and time budget of the issues of all epics?

Tags: jira, dashboard, jql

I´m trying to create a gadget for the Jira Dashboard that´s quite hard to accomplish.

**I need to show a list of epics with time budget and the sum of time spent as columns.**

The problem I´m facing is that the time logged is not made in the epics, but in the tasks or issues inside the epic (as I think it should be) and the column on "sum of time spent" is always empty.

This means, as I see it, that I have to be able to sum up the issues inside every epic and somehow show it in the empty column of the epic I need to see.

I created a filter and I´m calling it with the "filter results" jira dashboard gadget.

I tried with the Script Runner plugin and read the API it has, but still no idea how can that be done.

Is there any idea?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked for something exactly like this recently, and am surprised that JIRA doesn't have a way to do this out of the box.

Checkout Epic Sum Up. https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/aptis.plugins.epicSumUp/cloud/overview It will solve the Time Budget question, but I don't know about a Time Logged solution.

See:
https://confluence.aptis.info/display/ESU/Time+Field

"How to search a Time Field by using JQL"

You might also find some useful features in the Tempo Addon.
https://tempoplugin.jira.com/wiki/display/TEMPO/Tempo%20Timesheets%20Documentation

Since you're looking to display something on a dashboard look under the Users Guide: Tempo gadgets area.

Comment: Thanks for your answer strantheman.

I´ve already tried with Epic Sum Up and the tempo add-on is not enough, as far as I could see. 

Right now, I have Epics with the time budget and the stories/tasks have the sum of time spent... But still don´t know how to combine them or show the sum in the epic column of "sum of time spent".

Answer (score 0):

this works with the Plugin Timesheet 
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/294/timesheet-reports-and-gadgets?hosting=cloud&tab=overview

1) Add the Gadget to a JIRA-Dashboard 
2) Edit the Gadget appropiately 
  but care that you

**Group by: Epic Name** 
and choose for 
**Additional Fields: Original Estimate** and **Remaining Estimate**

Consider to set **Show Details:** to **No**

This will look something like this: 
(Remaining Estimate are the numbers Right from the Original Estimate-column ) 
[image]